# "May happen" is it correct?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, phrase-usage

I just want to know if it's correct to use "if I may happen" on this example: "If I may happen to have what you're looking for..."
English is not my first language so I'm confused about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### *If I happen to have what you're looking for...*

is perfectly natural and implies there is a possibility that the speaker has the thing in question. It is **certainly** possible.

> ### *If I may happen to have what you're looking for...*

sounds really weird but is technically correct, and implies the possibility that there is a possibility. Which is to say, it **may** be possible that the speaker has the thing. No idea when you would need this, however.

In conclusion, both are correct but I'm 99% sure you need to use the former (without *may*).

Hope this helps!